# "instance of" "type of" What is the use case of this?

Tags: java

While doing some casual reading I came across an interesting quote by Scott Meyers

> Anytime you find yourself writing
>   code of the form "if the object is of
>   type T1, then do something, but if
>   it's of type T2, then do something
>   else," slap yourself.

I was just wondering why Java has "instance of" operator when you could do the same thing by overridden methods? When is it actually used?

Comment: Maybe that's why he said *slap yourself*. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you have to use objects whose behavior (e.g. source code) you do not control so you cannot always rely on object-oriented solutions to type-related matters.  (Especially consider that authors of libraries cannot anticipate every use case you might have; of course, you could argue that extension and implementation provide workarounds but they require much more effort than direct type checking.)

The "instanceof" operator gives you a way to inspect the type of an object and act conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

It's ideal to avoid it, but sometimes necessary.

Use of instanceof can interfere with the Open/Closed Principle (the "O" in SOLID). If you implement instanceof tests, then your class may need to be modified as new implementation classes are created.

However, it is sometimes necessary. For example, it can be used in implementations of the `Object.equals()` method. The argument is an Object -- so that the method may be overridden by arbitrary subclasses -- but you usually need to cast it to your class's type to compare.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use it when I'm using a 3rd party library and classes are final (the jerks!).

An if-type-do-something in code is a sign that the do-something should be a method defined in the class or interface with overriding behavior. But that assumes you control the implementation. Sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm implementing `equals()` for a class `Foo` it often looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof Foo) {
    Foo that = (Foo) o;
    [ compare this to that ]
  } else {
  return false;
}
```

Since I'm overriding `equals` the signature is forced on me, but I need to know whether I have an instance of Foo or not for a meaningful comparison.

Comment: But that's only because equals is an ancient method and probably wouldn't be implemented that way today. Defining a generic Equatable interface like it's done for Comparable would be much nicer and would avoid this problem (Sure you couldn't put arbitrary objects into collections, but then that's hardly good style either)

Comment: @Voo: good point, but ancient or not, "equals" is a critical method of the Java platform, there's no way to avoid it in non-trivial programs.

Comment: @Voo good point. I can't say I like writing `equals` like this, it is just the case where I most often use `instanceof`

Comment: @Voo -- Type erasure makes the equals() method still useful in some cases, regardless of the introduction of generics.

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
public void eat(Eatable eatable){
  if(eatable instanceof fruit){
    //direct eat
  }
}
```

---

```
class Eatable {
}
```

---

```
class Fruit extends Eatable {
}
```

Comment: Well, that's an example of _how_ to use `instanceof`, but doesn't shed much light on _why_ it's in the language.

Answer (score 0):

While writing complicated class structure like in Wrapper design pattern, you never know what kind of object u will encounter. In these situation you check the object with instance of operator.